# Converting polar to Cartesian form

Tags: trigonometry, polar-coordinates

I have the given equation:

$r^3=2 \sin(\phi+\theta)$,

where $\theta$ = $\arccos(1/\sqrt{3})$ and $\phi$ is not given.

If I want to convert it to Cartesian form, is it simply sufficient to interpret $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and derive that $\phi=\pi-\theta$?

The problem is that I cannot be sure that $\phi=\pi-\theta$. Does this always regard  trigonometric functions?

Comment: So just to be clear, is $\phi$ the polar angle?

Comment: I think $\theta$ is the polar angle.

Comment: But you say $\theta$ is a constant and $\phi$ is not known. Did you write the other way round?

Comment: In any case expand $\sin (\theta+\phi)$ and if $\phi$ is the polar angle, $\cos \phi = x / \sqrt{x^2+y^2}, \sin \phi = y / \sqrt{x^2+y^2}, r = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$. Then simplify and that is your equation in cartesian.

Comment: Got it! Thanks!